# Whats wrong with my error trapping function?

Tags: vb.net, function

I have a program for buying shirts, I'm changing it so the error trapping happens through a function, so I deleted my previous error trapping, created the function, and tried it out. But somewhere I must of screwed up, because it's not working properly. I was following step by step the video guide from my class, but I can't find where I went wrong. I've been trying to figure it out for a few hours now but have gotten nowhere. Any help would be appreciated. What's happening is when I click Calculate or Next Sale, it will always give me my error message "Please enter a valid number" I've tried entering 0, 1, 25, 50, 51, 55, and 5a. It should give me an error message for 5a saying "Please enter a valid number", because it's not numeric. And it should give me the error message "Please enter a number from 1 to 50" for 0, 51, and 55. I couldn't even get that error message to work because every number I entered gave the "Please enter a valid number" error message. Where did I go wrong? Help me find the error please.

Here is the function:

```
    Private Function CheckTextBox(ByVal TextBoxName As TextBox, ByVal Min As Single, ByVal Max As Single, ByVal IntCheck As Boolean) As Boolean

    If Not IsNumeric(TextBoxName) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        TextBoxName.Text = ""
        TextBoxName.Focus()
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Val(TextBoxName.Text) < Min Or Val(TextBoxName.Text) > Max Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number from " & Min & " to " & Max, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        TextBoxName.Text = ""
        TextBoxName.Focus()
        Exit Function
    End If

    If IntCheck Then
        If Val(TextBoxName.Text) <> Int(TextBoxName.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            TextBoxName.Text = ""
            TextBoxName.Focus()
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    Return True

End Function
```

Here is the code for the Calculate button:

```
    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    'Local Variable Declaration Section
    Dim sngSalesTax As Single
    Dim sngOrderTotal As Single
    Dim intQuantity As Integer
    Dim sngItemTotal As Single
    'Data Input Section
    If msngShippingCost = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please choose a shipping method", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)    'Displays an error messsage when no shipping method is chosen
        Exit Sub 'Terminates the click event to allow shipping method to be chosen first
    End If

    If CheckTextBox(txtQuantity, 1, 50, True) = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    intQuantity = CInt(txtQuantity.Text)   'not sure if this line is needed?


    'Calculation Section
    sngItemTotal = msngItemPrice * intQuantity
    msngSubtotal += sngItemTotal     'Calculates the subtotal
    sngSalesTax = msngSubtotal * csngSalesTaxRate    'Calculates Sales Tax based on the sales tax rate constant
    sngOrderTotal = msngSubtotal + sngSalesTax + msngShippingCost 'Calculates total for the sale
    mintOrdersPlacedToday = mintOrdersPlacedToday + 1   'Calculates the number of orders placed today, adds one to the previous number
    msngTotalOfOrdersToday = msngTotalOfOrdersToday + sngOrderTotal 'Calculates the Total of all the orders placed today
    'Output section

    lblShowSubTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(msngSubtotal)  'Displays the Sub Total
    lblShowSalesTax.Text = FormatCurrency(sngSalesTax)  'Displays the Sales Tax
    lblShowOrderTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(sngOrderTotal)  'Displays the Order Total
    lblShowOrdersPlacedToday.Text = mintOrdersPlacedToday   'Displays the Orders placed today
    lblShowTotalOfOrders.Text = FormatCurrency(msngTotalOfOrdersToday)  'Displays the Total of the Orders placed today
    lblShowShippingCost.Text = FormatCurrency(msngShippingCost)  'Displays the total of the shipping cost


End Sub
```

And here is the code for the next item button:

```
    Private Sub btnNextItem_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNextItem.Click
    'Local Variable Declaration Section
    Dim sngSalesTax As Single
    Dim intQuantity As Integer
    Dim sngItemTotal As Single
    'Data Input Section

    If CheckTextBox(txtQuantity, 1, 50, True) = False Then 'Uses the function to error trap exits sub if functions returns as false
        Exit Sub
    End If

    intQuantity = CInt(txtQuantity.Text)

        'Calculation Section
        sngItemTotal = msngItemPrice * intQuantity 'Calculates item total
        msngSubtotal += sngItemTotal     'Calculates the subtotal
        sngSalesTax = msngSubtotal * csngSalesTaxRate    'Calculates Sales Tax based on the sales tax rate constant
        'Output section
        lblShowShippingCost.Text = ""
        lblShowOrderTotal.Text = ""
        lblShowSubTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(msngSubtotal)  'Displays the Sub Total
        lblShowSalesTax.Text = FormatCurrency(sngSalesTax)  'Displays the Sales Tax
End Sub
```

Comment: The first If statement in your function should be `If Not IsNumeric(TextBoxName.Text) Then`. You left of the `.Text` although you included it in the other statements.

Comment: Are you in the same class as the asker of this question: [Visual Basic - Input Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30358814/1115360)?

Comment: In your `CheckTextBox` function, you should also replace all occurrences of `Exit Function` with `Return False`.